# Powershell script to resolve DNS name display result

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to modify the below script so the output of the result can be like in the expected order (failed result at the bottom) and also the additional indicator which shows **ExternalDNSServers** or **DomainControllers**.

Script:

```
Clear-Host
#region Define Exit Codes
$ExitCode = @{ "Up" = 0;
    "Down"          = 1;
    "Warning"       = 2;
    "Critical"      = 3;
    "Unknown"       = 4
}
#endregion Define Exit Codes

##################### Modifiable Variables#####################

if ( $args[0] ) {
    $LookupName = $args[0]
}
else {
    $LookupName = "booking.com", "hotel.com", "143.22.57.221", "221.78.96.41"
}

$ExternalDNSServers = @('1.1.1.1', '8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4', '208.67.222.222', '208.67.220.220')

################################################################

#####################Main#####################

# Clear out any errors that exist
$Error.Clear()

ForEach ($URL in $LookupName) {
    # Try..catch..finally block to try the looking
    try {
        # Let's get some Active Directory information
        $AdForest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()

        # Using that, let's extract the names of the domain controllers
        $DomainControllers = $ADforest.Sites | ForEach-Object { $_.Servers } | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
        $DomainControllers += $ExternalDNSServers

        # Create Empty Collection for All Domain Controllers DNS Results
        $Results = @()

        # Cycle through each of them and do a single test
        ForEach ($DomainController in $DomainControllers) {
            # Using .NET, let's do a DNS lookup and see how long it takes
            $Measurement = Measure-Command -Expression { [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($URL).Hostname } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalMilliseconds

            # Now that we've gotten the time it took to do the work, let's use that and record it with the domain controller into a new object.
            # Then using the '+=', we'll add it to the collection
            $Results += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ DomainController = $DomainController; TotalMilliseconds = $Measurement }
        }
        # We need to sort the results by the speed - shortest time first
        $Results = $Results | Sort-Object -Property TotalMilliseconds

        # $Results
        Write-Host "`nURL: $($URL) - $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($URL) | where-object {$_.AddressFamily -notlike "InterNetworkV6"} | foreach-object {echo $_.IPAddressToString })" -BackgroundColor DarkBlue -ForegroundColor Yellow
        # Let's output the results
        # Since it's sorted, the first is the fastest.  We reference the first object in a collection by referencing  it with [0]
        Write-Host "Message.Fastest: $( $Results[0].DomainController ) executes DNS lookup against '$URL' in $( $Results[0].TotalMilliseconds ) ms"
        #Write-Host "Statistic.Fastest: $( $Results[0].TotalMilliseconds ) ms"

        # We need to calculate the average of all of them - so we measure the TotalMilliseconds and ask it to be averaged
        $Average = $Results | Measure-Object -Property TotalMilliseconds -Average | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average
        Write-Host "Message.Average: Average DNS lookups against '$URL' takes $([Math]::Round($Average,4)) ms"
        #Write-Host "Statistic.Average: $Average ms"

        # Since it's sorted, the last is the slowest.  We reference the last object in a collection by referencing it with [-1]
        Write-Host "Message.Slowest: $( $Results[-1].DomainController ) executes DNS lookup against '$URL' in $( $Results[-1].TotalMilliseconds ) ms"
        #Write-Host "Statistic.Slowest: $( $Results[-1].TotalMilliseconds ) ms"

        $Status = "Up"

    }
    catch {
        # any errors
        # We still need to output the same number (and names) of statistics just for template happiness
        $Status = "Down"
        Write-Warning "`nURL: $($URL) - $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($URL) | where-object {$_.AddressFamily -notlike "InterNetworkV6"} | foreach-object {echo $_.IPAddressToString })"
    }
}

finally {
    # Now we finally exit out of the script
    # Comment this out if you are testing this is the CLI or an IDE
    exit $ExitCode[$Status]
}
```

Existing output:

> ```
> URL: booking.com - 5.57.16.220
> Message.Fastest: 208.67.222.222 executes DNS lookup against 'booking.com' in 0.1917 ms
> Message.Average: Average DNS lookups against 'booking.com' takes 0.2729 ms
> Message.Slowest: PRDDC01-VM.domain.com executes DNS lookup against 'booking.com' in 0.8323 ms
>
> URL: hotel.com - 204.74.99.101
> Message.Fastest: PRDDC31-VM.domain.com executes DNS lookup against 'hotel.com' in 0.1784 ms
> Message.Average: Average DNS lookups against 'hotel.com' takes 0.2143 ms
> Message.Slowest: PRDDC01-VM.domain.com executes DNS lookup against 'hotel.com' in 0.2994 ms
> WARNING: 
> URL: 143.22.57.221 - 143.22.57.221
>
> URL: 221.78.96.41 - 221.78.96.41
> Message.Fastest: PRDDC05-VM.domain.com executes DNS lookup against '221.78.96.41' in 0.2842 ms
> Message.Average: Average DNS lookups against '221.78.96.41' takes 206.3181 ms
> Message.Slowest: 8.8.8.8 executes DNS lookup against '221.78.96.41' in 4737.366 ms
> ```

Expected output:

> ```
> URL: booking.com - 5.57.16.220
> Message.Fastest: 208.67.222.222 executes DNS lookup against 'booking.com' in 0.1917 ms - [**ExternalDNSServers**]
> Message.Average: Average DNS lookups against 'booking.com' takes 0.2729 ms
> Message.Slowest: PRDDC01-VM executes DNS lookup against 'booking.com' in 0.8323 ms - [**DomainControllers**]
>
> URL: hotel.com - 204.74.99.101
> Message.Fastest: PRDDC31-VM executes DNS lookup against 'hotel.com' in 0.1784 ms - [**DomainControllers**]
> Message.Average: Average DNS lookups against 'hotel.com' takes 0.2143 ms
> Message.Slowest: PRDDC01-VM executes DNS lookup against 'hotel.com' in 0.2994 ms - [**DomainControllers**]
>
> URL: 221.78.96.41 - 221.78.96.41
> Message.Fastest: PRDDC05-VM executes DNS lookup against '221.78.96.41' in 0.2842 ms - [**DomainControllers**]
> Message.Average: Average DNS lookups against '221.78.96.41' takes 206.3181 ms
> Message.Slowest: 8.8.8.8 executes DNS lookup against '221.78.96.41' in 4737.366 ms - [**ExternalDNSServers**]
>
> URL: 143.22.57.221 - N/A
> Cannot resolve 143.22.57.221
> ```

I wonder if the above DNS server type indicator is possible?

Comment: The code you posted will not run because it has syntax errors. $args[0] is not set anywhere, thus will error out The 'finally block' should be in the loop with the Try/Catch or it will error out. Why are you not just using the PowerShell DNS cmdlets, the are available via the RSAT tools, which can be enabled on Win7-WIn 10 and any Windows Server edition. ['Install RSAT'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=install%20rsat&form=ANNTH1&refig=5b859669647244ffb6f288dda08bdf15&sp=-1&pq=install%20rs&sc=8-10&qs=n&sk=&cvid=5b859669647244ffb6f288dda08bdf15).

Comment: @postanote, actually it runs well.
It's just the result need some modification.
THe reason I did not use Resolve-DNS is that I need this script to be portable without installing RSAT.

Comment: You are aware that the script doesn't test different DNS-servers, right? You only use `$DomainController` in the output-object as the methods in System.Net.Dns doesn't support specifying a nameserver. All queries use the nameserver set for the preferred network adapter. Should also mention that the finally-block cannot be used away from the try/catch-blocks + you should build the DomainControllers (would call it DNSServers) list before the foreach url-loop.

Comment: Yes @FrodeF., I'm aware of it. The variable $DomainController is also +=ExternalDNSServers  or added with a few external DNS servers if you notice in the  source code above I posted.

Comment: I noticed that you added additional DNS-servers which is why I made a tip to rename the complete array (`$DNSServers = $DomainControllers + $ExternalDNSServers`) :-). However, the array still doesn't do anything since all `GetHostEntry()` calls will use the same nameserver.

Comment: Hm.. so is there any way to configure it so that it can use different DNS server?

Comment: Understood about the RSAT thing, but it does not have to be installed either. If you can reach a DC/DNS server (or any host with RSAT installed), you can use the RSAT cmdlets, via PowerShell implicit remoting. As GetHostEntry(), as FrodeF point outs, it is bound by design to always call the same nameserver. To try and get around that, it requires way more work. Meaning 3rd Party stuff. [For Example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/8b5fe9a3-5da0-41e0-a7f9-2cb6c5608f69/specifying-the-name-servers-for-systemnetdnsgethostentry)

Comment: postanote & Frode, That's great, many thanks for the pointer and it makes more sense. I will recode the script with Resolve-DNS as it is the most appropriate one to go with.